# Get instant shopify webhook

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want webhook instantly when any of the event occur in shopify. Webhook is working fine but **it's taking a time to reach our server** (Webhook end point url).

When ordering from the store, it takes a minimum of 3 seconds and a **maximum of 8 seconds** to reach webhook end point url.

So there is any option to get instantly? Approximately in 2 or 3 seconds?

I need to manage live ordering in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is NOT how webhooks work. The reason is, you are just a subscriber. You get your webhook delivered when the publisher can deliver it, which is almost never instantly. While not common, people have waited hours and sometimes longer due to network congestion or other failures.

While you think it is important to get them instantly now, perhaps you should attempt to reframe your efforts around receiving them, processing them properly when you do, and then and only then, try and mitigate any actual problems with those results, as best you can.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback.

Yes, that i understand. I was just assuming if there is any way to get it instantly.
And yes we have already processed it from our side which is very faster we are processing those data in just 0.18 sec.


But we are getting webhook after 3 or 8 seconds when order placed in shopify.

Comment: You will forever be getting orders in N seconds, or N minutes, or heck, even N hours. Sometimes Shopify is late with webhooks by an entire day. That is just how our distributed and networked world works. No one offers instant webhooks.